# Simple Many-to-Many issue in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm adding Flask-Admin to an existing Flask app (using Python 3, and MySQL with SQLAlchemy), and I simply cannot figure out how to get a many-to-many relationship to render correctly. I've read a number of questions about this here, and it looks like I am following the right practices.

I have a `Quotation` table, a `Subject` table, and a `QuotationSubject` table, which has to be an actual class rather than an association table, but I don't care about the extra columns in the association table for this purpose; they're things like `last_modified` that I don't need to display or edit. The relationships seem to work in the rest of the application.

Trimming out the fields and definitions that don't matter here, I have:

```py
class Quotation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'quotation'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    word = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    created = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, default=db.func.now())
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())

    subject = db.relationship("QuotationSubject", back_populates="quotation")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word

class Subject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subject'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, default=db.func.now())
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())

    quotation = db.relationship("QuotationSubject", back_populates="subject")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class QuotationSubject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'quotation_subject'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    quotation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quotation.id'), default=0, nullable=False)
    subject_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subject.id'), default=0, nullable=False)
    created = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, default=db.func.now())
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())

    quotation = db.relationship('Quotation', back_populates='subject', lazy='joined')
    subject = db.relationship('Subject', back_populates='quotation', lazy='joined')
```

In my `admin.py`, I simply have:

```py
class QuotationModelView(ModelView):
    column_searchable_list = ['word', 'description']

    form_excluded_columns = ['created', 'last_modified']
    column_list = ('word', 'subject')


admin.add_view(QuotationModelView(Quotation, db.session))
```

And that's it.

In my `list` view, instead of seeing `subject` values, I get the associated entry in the `QuotationSubject` table, e.g.

```
test    <QuotationSubject 1>, <QuotationSubject 17>, <QuotationSubject 18>
book    <QuotationSubject 2>
```

Similarly, in my `create` view, instead of getting a list of a dozen or so subjects, I get an enormous list of everything from the QuotationSubject table.

I've looked at some of the `inline_models` stuff, suggested by some posts here, which also hasn't worked, but in any case there are other posts (e.g. [Flask-Admin view with many to many relationship model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452927/flask-admin-view-with-many-to-many-relationship-model)) which suggest that what I'm doing should work. I'd be grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I fear there's something missing from your question because I don't see the `Citation` class defined. But that doesn't seem to be the problem.

The most classic example of many-to-many relationships in Flask is roles to users. Here is what a working role to user M2M relationship can look like:

```
class RolesUsers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles_users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))

class Role(RoleMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='roles_users',
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

And in Flask-Admin:

```
from user.models import User, Role

admin.add_view(PVCUserView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(PVCModelView(Role, db.session))
```

Note that the relationship is only declared once, with a `backref` so it's two-way. It looks like you're using `back_populates` for this, which [I believe is equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870250/1749551).

For the case you're describing, it looks like your code declares relationships directly to the M2M table. Is this really what you want? You say that you don't need access to the extra columns in the QuotationSubject table for Flask-Admin. But do you need them elsewhere? It seems very odd to me to have a call to `quotation` or `subject` actually return an instance of `QuotationSubject`. I believe this is why Flask-Admin is listing all the QuotationSubject rows in the create view.

So my recommendation would be to try setting your relationships to point directly to the target model class while putting the M2M table as the `secondary`.

If you want to access the association model in other places (and if it really can't be an [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) for some reason) then create a second relationship in each model class which explicitly points to it. You will then likely need to exclude that relationship in Flask-Admin using `form_excluded_columns` and `column_exclude_list`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The "Citation" was a typo for "Quotation"; I had to retype some of this; I fixed it in editing. For the relationship issue, I was trying to very closely follow the many-to-many guidelines in the SQLA docs, at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many. For the Association Object example, it does show the joins to the M2M table, but re-reading it, it is the case that this isn't meant to be the main way of hitting the other-side model. I'll make the adjustments; thanks for the pointer!